# Connect Google Sheet to localhost MySQL with JDBC Services

Tags: mysql, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to use the JDBC Services of Google App Scripts to connect a Google Sheet to a **local** implementation I have on my computer of SQL Server (hosted on 127.0.0.1:3306).

I tried the following script :

```
// Replace the variables in this block with real values.
var address = 'database_IP_address';
var user = 'user_name';
var userPwd = 'user_password';
var db = 'database_name';

var dbUrl = 'jdbc:mysql://' + address + '/' + db;

// Read up to 1000 rows of data from the table and log them.
function readFromTable() {
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);

  var start = new Date();
  var stmt = conn.createStatement();
  stmt.setMaxRows(1000);
  var results = stmt.executeQuery('SELECT * FROM entries');
  var numCols = results.getMetaData().getColumnCount();

  while (results.next()) {
    var rowString = '';
    for (var col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
      rowString += results.getString(col + 1) + '\t';
    }
    Logger.log(rowString)
  }

  results.close();
  stmt.close();

  var end = new Date();
  Logger.log('Time elapsed: %sms', end - start);
}
```

with address = `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`
user/password : from a specific user I created with all access to db and able to access from anywhere.
database: my database name

This is returning me the following error :
`Exception: Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string, username and password.`

Tried looking at similar problems but could not find something about LOCALHOST sql server.
Saw some problematics about allowing IPs to reach my database, but I am not sure how does this applies in my case since it is hosted on my local computer and I just want to make a demo for the moment so it will stay that way.

Note : I created my sql-server through MySQL Workbench/MySQL Server

How can I proceed ?

Comment: SQL Server and MySQL are not the same thing. Please clarify which one you are actually using (presumably MySQL) and remove the tag for the other.

Comment: I'd like to point out that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31105466/14606045) might also be helpful to you. Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43965348/can-not-connect-to-local-mysql-server-thru-apps-script-jdbc) for more visual guide on port forwarding and granting permission which is similar to the previous link.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this error several times and randomly "Exception: Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string, username and password."
I found [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36756432) and [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/210491249) issues opened in google issue tracker, thought it could be helpful for someone finding this exact question someday.

In my case the problem was the MS SQL version that was not supporting TLS 1.2. An updated version fixed the problem.